# ¿Cómo incrementar el TIMEOUT de una llamada AJAX para mostrar la respuesta del Controladoor?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-core, promesas

Ejecuto una llamada AJAX a un método dentro de un controlador en ASP.NET CORE 6.0, el problema que tengo es que, aunque todo el código del método se ejecuta de forma exitosa la respuesta no regresa al cliente, lo mas seguro es que esta respuesta ("PROMISE") se pierda ya que esta tarda 13 minutos en retornar.

*Incremente el TIMEOUT de la llamada AJAX, pero aun así no muestra la respuesta que especifico dentro del código JavaScript.*

¿Cómo puedo resolver esto?

Codigo JS:

```
function UploadFileMethod() {
        var input = document.getElementById('theFile');
        var files = input.files;
    
        if (files.length == 0) {
            toastr.warning("Debe elegir un archivo");
            return false;
         }
        else if (files.length > 1) {
            toastr.warning("Solo puede subir un archivo a la vez");
            return false;
        }
    
        var formData = new FormData();
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            formData.append('file', files[i]);
        }
    
        $('#loading').show();
    
        $.ajax({
                url: urlUploadFile,
                data: formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                type: "POST",
                timeout: 780000000000, 
                success: function (data)
                {
                    console.log(data);
                    if (data.estado) {
                        console.log(data.tercero);
                        toastr.success(data.mensaje);
                        $('#theFile').val('');
                        $('#tablaTercero tbody tr').remove();
                        $.each(data.tercero, function (index, item) {
                            let tr = `<tr>
                          <td> ${item.numero} </td>
                          <td> ${item.nit} </td>
                          <td> ${item.nombre} </td>
                          <td> ${item.fechaInicio} </td>
                          </tr>`;
                           $('#tablaTercero tbody').append(tr);
                        });
                        $('#loading').hide();
                    }
                    else {
                        toastr.error(data.mensaje);
                        $('#loading').hide();
                    }
                }, error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                   {
                     $('#tablaTercero tbody tr').remove();
                     $('#loading').hide();
                     toastr.error('ERROR INESPERADO: ' + textStatus + ' ' + jqXHR + ' ' + errorThrown);
                }
        });
    
        return false;
    }
```

Codigo C#

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult UploadFileMethod(IFormFile file)
        {
            var respuesta = new ParametrosModel();
            respuesta.Estado = false;
            var logPath = this._webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath + AdobePdfApi.log_excepcion;
            Helper.WriteFileLog(logPath, "ENTRADA");

            if (file != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    var p = file.FileName.Replace("_", "").Replace("/", "").Replace(" ", "").Replace("-", "").Split('.');
                    var identificador = Helper.CreateUniqueidentifier();
                    var strIdentificador = identificador.ToString().ToUpper();
                    var name = p[0] + "_" + strIdentificador + "_.pdf".Replace(" ", "");

                    if (file.FileName.ToUpper().Contains(".PDF"))
                    {
                        Helper.CreateFolder(this._webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, strIdentificador);
                        var pathReadFile = this._webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath + AdobePdfApi.pdf_filesToWrite + "F_" + strIdentificador + "\\" + name;
                        var stream = System.IO.File.Create(pathReadFile);
                        file.CopyTo(stream);
                        stream.Dispose();
                        
                        PdfDocument filePdf = PdfReader.Open(pathReadFile, PdfDocumentOpenMode.InformationOnly );
                        var numberPages = filePdf.PageCount;
                        filePdf.Dispose();

                        var pathCredenciales = this._webHostEnvironment.ContentRootPath + AdobePdfApi.file_credentials;
                        var pathFileSave = this._webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath + AdobePdfApi.pdf_filesExtract + "F_" + strIdentificador + "\\";
                        var pathReadJson = this._webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath + AdobePdfApi.pdf_filesToRead + "F_" + strIdentificador + "\\";
                        
                        if (numberPages > 20)
                        {
                            respuesta = AdobeSplitFile.SplitFile(pathCredenciales, pathReadFile, strIdentificador,logPath);
                            Helper.WriteFileLog(logPath, "SPLIT");
                            if (respuesta.Estado)
                            {
                                var acumuladorTercero  = new List<Tercero>();
                                int indice = 0;
                                foreach (var pathReadFile_ in respuesta.PathFile)
                                {
                                    respuesta = AdobeExtractInfo.ExtractInfo(pathCredenciales, pathReadFile_, pathFileSave, strIdentificador,logPath, indice.ToString ());
                                    Helper.WriteFileLog(logPath, "EXTRACION Nº: " + indice.ToString());
                                    if (respuesta.Estado)
                                    {
                                        ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(respuesta.PathArchivo, pathReadJson, true);
                                        var t = this._readFileService.LeerArchivo(pathReadJson + "structuredData.json", identificador);
                                        if (t.Count > 0)
                                        {
                                            Helper.WriteFileLog(logPath, "GUARDANDO REGISTROS Nº: " +indice.ToString ());
                                            acumuladorTercero.AddRange(t);
                                        }
                                        indice++;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        Helper.WriteFileLog(logPath, respuesta .Mensaje );
                                        return Json(respuesta);
                                    }
                                }
                                respuesta.Tercero = new List<Tercero>();
                                respuesta.Tercero = acumuladorTercero;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                return Json(respuesta);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            respuesta = AdobeExtractInfo.ExtractInfo(pathCredenciales, pathReadFile, pathFileSave, strIdentificador, logPath);
                            if (respuesta.Estado)
                            {
                                ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(respuesta.PathArchivo, pathReadJson, true);
                                respuesta.Tercero = this._readFileService.LeerArchivo(pathReadJson + "structuredData.json",identificador);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                return Json(respuesta);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Helper.WriteFileLog(logPath, "El archivo debe ser de de extencion .pdf");
                        respuesta.Mensaje  = "El archivo debe ser de de extension .pdf";
                        return Json(respuesta);
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Helper.WriteFileLog(logPath, ex.ToString());
                    respuesta.Mensaje = ex.Message;
                    return Json(respuesta);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Helper.WriteFileLog(logPath, "El valor no puede ser nulo");
                respuesta.Mensaje = "El valor no puede ser nulo";
            }

            Helper.WriteFileLog(logPath, "Archivo cargado correctamente");
            respuesta.Mensaje = "Archivo cargado correctamente";
            respuesta.Estado = true;
            return Json(respuesta);
        }
```

Comment: ¿Pero qué error tienes? ¿Es seguro que el problema es el timeout?

Comment: si le pones timeout:0  este no tendra un tiemout y quedara esperando hasta que otro evento lo cancele. Pero si tu proceso tarda tanto en retornar a lo mejor deberias re pensar el metodo y utilizar algun administrador de jobs.

Comment: ponle timeout 0 para que no tenga limite de tiempo y además agrega tu ajax a un trycatch ya que abortar una llamada no es capturada por timeout ni ningún error dentro de ajax. Además tu servicio tiene un timeout diferente al del cliente, revisa esto también